# ImportError in candlestick example from matplotlib documentation: `cannot import name quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc`

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and I'm struggling to run this example in the matplotlib documentation:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html

I'm basically copying the code 1:1 into my Python file and when I try to run it I get the error shown below:

```
File "plot.py", line 5, in <module>
    from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc, candlestick_ohlc
ImportError: cannot import name quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc
```

I get the same results in my Mac and on my Linux box, so I'm assuming it has something to do with the installation or it is missing a dependency. On Linux I've installed via `apt-get install`, on the Mac I've used `pip`.

Any help or troubleshooting info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using (`print(matplotlib.__version__)`)?

Comment: after matplotlib==1.5.1 only available  quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc method. please try greater than 1.5.1

Answer (score 3):

Yep, I get the same.

So at the cursor prompt I typed:

```
import matplotlib

dir(matplotlib.finance)
```

...and I saw similar items except no "_ohlc" at the end.

```
['Affine2D', 'Line2D', 'LineCollection', 'PolyCollection', 'Rectangle',
 'TICKLEFT', 'TICKRIGHT', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__',
 '__name__', '__package__', 'cachedir', 'candlestick', 'candlestick2',
 'colorConverter', 'contextlib', 'date2num', 'datetime', 'division',
 'fetch_historical_yahoo', 'get_cachedir', 'index_bar', 'iterable',
 'md5', 'mkdirs', 'np', 'os', 'parse_yahoo_historical', 'plot_day_summary',
 'plot_day_summary2', 'print_function', 'quotes_historical_yahoo',
 'stock_dt', 'sys', 'urlopen', 'verbose', 'volume_overlay',
 'volume_overlay2', 'volume_overlay3', 'warnings']
```

So I just deleted the last five letters `_ohlc` everywhere to see what happens, and it works for me now. I am not sure this is really 100% correct though. There was some [activity](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1920/) in 2013 by @tcaswell...

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator,\
    DayLocator, MONDAY
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo, candlestick    # _ohlc deleted


# (Year, month, day) tuples suffice as args for quotes_historical_yahoo
date1 = (2004, 2, 1)
date2 = (2004, 4, 12)


mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo('INTC', date1, date2)  # _ohlc deleted
if len(quotes) == 0:
    raise SystemExit

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dayFormatter)

#plot_day_summary(ax, quotes, ticksize=3)
candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.6)  # _ohlc deleted

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

Comment: OK great. If you feel it's good enough to accept, don't forget the "accept" button.